why does excel generate a bar graph with categories not in the order of my liking and how can i fix it?
In excel, how come the bar chart categories aren't arranged the way the tables were arranged? How can i fix this? For instance, I already arranged the rows as 1234567 and made a bar chart. However, the resulting order of the bar chart became 7654321enter image description here. According to both chatgpt and bing it's really how Excel processes the data. So is there any way I can fix this, because I really need the categories in this order.
tried numbering them to let them know of the sequence. tried pasting only the values of the table in another sheet to get rid of the formula

Select the 2 parameters as on the screenshot for the Category Axis.


Amazing that you good humoured ly answer this question! seeing y value decreasing as it moves away from x axis is just hilarious….but still good to know Excel does support this. I didn’t know it until today..

Another way to resolve this is to simply write your data in the order of 7654321. like below.

Still, I can't help pointing out making Y value decrease as it moves away from x-axis is in violation of mathematics...but it is your choice...

hi. i basically numbered it to hide my data, but they were text categories. i get your point now thanks!
